# Write a Python function that will receive a list as a parameter and count if the list repeats any number/s

Tags: python, list, python-3.5

I just need some help with this question here. All the details are in the below mentioned question. I have done a solution, but i am kind of stuck onto this one thing, would really appreciate if someone could guide me into the correct direction.

PROBLEM: whenever i run my program, it always says "You have: three 5" even though the number repeating three times is not 5. Hopefully that makes sense. My program is below the question.

The above grid can be represented in Python as a list variable like `grid = [2,2,1,3,2]`

Write a Python function pokieTester(list) that will receive a list as a parameter and

 Count if the list has 3,4 or 5 numbers that are the same

 It will return a list containing 2 items:

```
o The first item will be the number of repeated numbers
o The second item will be the value of repeated numbers
```

Write a Python function makeList() that has no parameters and returns a list of 5 random integers (between 1 and 5 inclusive)

Combine your functions into a program that displays appropriate text, saying if the user has won or lost.

(You lose if you do not have 3, 4 or 5 numbers the same.)

For example:
YOU WIN! or Sorry you lose

If they win, it should display how many repeated numbers and their value.

For example:

YOU WIN! You have three 2’s

======
HERE IS MY PROGRAM=====

```
import random

def pokieTester(countList):

    count = countList.count(0)

    for num in [1,2,3,4,5]:
        if count < 3:
            count = countList.count(num)
    demoList = [count, num]        
    return demoList


def makeList():

    numList = []

    for count in [0,1,2,3,4]:
        a = random.randint(1,5)
        numList.append(a)
    return numList

gameList = makeList()

print (gameList)

matches = pokieTester(gameList)

count = matches[0]

num = matches[1]


num_List = ['three','four','five']

if count > 2:

        print ("You win")
        print ("You have: " , end = '' )

        if count == 3:
           print (num_List[0], num, end = '')

        elif count == 4:
           print (num_List[1], num, end ='')

        elif count == 5:
           print (num_List[2], num, end ='')

else:

    print ("Sorry, You lose")
```

Answer (score 1):

In `pokieTester()`, at the end of the for loop `num` will always be 5 because the loop always executes five times. You need to break out of the loop early if you detect that `count` >= 3. Try this:

```
def pokieTester(countList):
    for num in [1,2,3,4,5]:
        count = countList.count(num)
        if count >= 3:
            # there are 3, 4 or 5 instances of num
            return [count, num]
    return [0, 0]
```

The spec is loose wrt what the return value should be if there are not 3 or more of any number, so the above function will just return `[0, 0]`, but it could arguably return `None`.

The calling code can be simplified by using a dictionary instead of list `num_List`. Then you can retrieve the text version of the number using `count` as the key:

```
num_text = {3: 'three', 4: 'four', 5: 'five'}
count, num = pokieTester(gameList)
if count >= 3:
    print("You win")
    print("You have: {} {} s".format(num_text[count], num)
```

Comment: Hey, i replaced my "def pokieTester" with the one you provided, and it works just fine. So if its not too much trouble, may i ask what does the second part mean? Sorry about the trouble, I'm fairly new to python, still trying to understand everything. Is the second part necessary? Thanks

Comment: The second part is just a simpler way to write the code that calls `pokieTester()`. A dictionary is a better data structure for mapping a key value (in this case the count) to a value (in this case text for the count). Once you have that you can go directly from the count to the text representation without a whole bunch of if statements.

Comment: Oh ok, starting to understand it. Do i need to put the second part in my code or is it just there so its easier and makes much more sense.

Comment: @Zubin: in general less code is better. It's more flexible and easier to modify later. The way that you have done it with the `if/elif` statements requires a lot more code to do the same thing. Also it's a bit pointless to test, for example, `count == 3` and then index into the list - why not simply hardcode "three" in the `print` statement.

Answer (score 0):

```
import random
from collections import Counter
from operator import itemgetter

numerals = ('one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five')

numbers = [random.randint(1, 5) for x in range(5)]
print(numbers)

matche = max(Counter(numbers).items(), key=itemgetter(1))
count = matche[1]
number = matche[0]

if count > 2:
        print("You win!\nYou have: {} {}".format(numerals[count-1], number))
else:
    print("Sorry, You lose")
```

Comment: While this is definitely a better way to do it, it does not help the OP to understand why their code (which is obviously homework) does not work, nor how they could fix their existing code. Dumping code without explanation is not helpful.

Comment: Hey, thanks for your time but because I'm a student, we are not allowed to use collections.counter or operator itemgetter, just have to use basic stuff.

Comment: @mhawke You're right. But I know Python is much better than the English, so sometimes it's easier for me to answer code.

Answer (score 0):

```
import random

randlist = [random.randint(1,5) for i in range(5)]

def pokieTest(randlist):
    num_List = {3: 'three', 4: 'four', 5: 'five'}
    for i in randlist:
        count = randlist.count(i)
        if count in num_List.keys():
            return [num_List[count], i]


print randlist

result = pokieTest(randlist)

if result:
    print "You win!"
    print "You have: ", result
else:
    print "Sorry, you lose"
```